# Curved navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, I have a library in flutter https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar and already implemented it in my project, but the problem is that when you navigating on item, icon color of selected item doesn't change. Is it possible to dynamically change icon color of selected item?

This is what by default:

[image]

And this is what I need:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
class HomeBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_HomeBottomNavigationBarState createState() =>_HomeBottomNavigationBarState();
}


class _HomeBottomNavigationBarState extends State<HomeBottomNavigationBar> 
{

int pressedButtonNo = 0;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return CurvedNavigationBar(
   
   items: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.add, size: 30, color: (pressedButtonNo = 0)? Colors.Green : Colors.Black,),
    Icon(Icons.list, size: 30, color: (pressedButtonNo = 1)? Colors.Green : Colors.Black,),
    Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30, color: (pressedButtonNo = 2)? Colors.Green : Colors.Black,),
  ],
  onTap: (index) {
    setState () {
     pressedButtonNo = index;
    }
  },
);
}}
```

I have not tested it. Hope it works!
Happy Coding:)

Comment: Hah, so simple solution)) Thank you so much, but what about elevation?))

Comment: I think it has got no elevation property, but there is always way for doing something. I think you can achieve it indirectly by adding a container at the end of body, (just below Curved navigation bar) and add BoxShadow property to it.

Comment: Your answer with changable icon colors was right, but instead of using stateless widget you need to use statefull widget!))

Comment: Solution with boxShadow doesn't work properly.. Seems need to create a custom shadow path, so the library became useless. I'll try to create a custom library)) I can't close this question yet, unfortunately.((

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is late i found a way to do it:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      _tabItems[_activePage],
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: CurvedNavigationBar(//your stuff),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Properties are there

1. buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.teal
2. backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   check out