# How can i make the below image BottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, customization, flutter-animation, flutter-packages, bottom-navigation-bar

If anyone have any package or sample code then please help me to create BottomNavigationBar like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This package is similar although does not have the exact same design [curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)

Answer (score 1):

Try building on this package [curved navigation bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)
and seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224246/curved-navigation-bar-in-flutter).

They both show very similar designs.